# using pathlib to open shelved files in python

Tags: python, windows, shelve, pathlib

I use pathlib to open textfiles  that  exists in a different directory, but get this error

```
TypeError:`"Unsupported operand type for +:'WindowsPath' and 'str'"
```

when I try opening a shelved file that exist in a score folder in the current directory like this.

```
from pathlib import *
import shelve

def read_shelve():
    data_folder = Path("score")
    file = data_folder / "myDB"
    myDB = shelve.open(file)
    return myDB
```

What am I doing wrong or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Apparently `shelve.open` hasn't been updated to support input paths based on the `__fspath__` protocol. So you'll have to manually pass `os.fspath(file)` instead of `file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[shelve.open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#shelve.open) requires filename as **string** but you provide `WindowsPath` object created by `Path`.

Solution would be to simply convert Path to string following [pathlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators) guidelines:

```
from pathlib import *
import shelve

def read_shelve():
    data_folder = Path("score")
    file = data_folder / "myDB"
    myDB = shelve.open(str(file))
    return myDB
```